# Why is Word 2010 dealing specially with the "[...]"?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, autocorrect

I have a weird problem with Microsoft Word 2010. I use another program to put text blocks into my Word documents, for stuff which I use a lot. Now one of those is the "[...]" placeholder. All fine so far.
Yet when I want to revert this, usually just using Ctrl+Z (German keyboard), then I'd expect it to delete the whole "[...]", but it doesn't! It only removes the "]" and then after another Ctrl+Z press the first "." and so on. But why?? I'm sure this is some stupid auto-correct setting, how do I find and delete it?

And is there any lesson I can learn from this about the system how Word "works" concerning auto-correct or reverting changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to check if you have anything setup for auto correct here

> File > Options > Proofing >
>   AutoCorrect Options

This could also be caused by your other program passing extra information to Word. I usually will remove all formatting by pasting what I want into notepad, copying it again, then pasting it into Word.